# Is a matrix similar to its transpose over $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-numbers

Is every $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (or even $\mathbb{Z}$) conjugate to its transpose via a matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

On the one hand, I know the analogous fact is false for matrices over $\mathbb{Z}$ with counterexamples constructed via the Latimer-MacDuffee theorem (but the only counterexamples I've seen break down in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for all $p$.)

On the other hand I know there are various conditions under which $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$-conjugacy implies $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$-conjugacy, as well as lifting criteria from $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$, so it seems possible that it could hold here.

Comment: The word "any" is sometimes confusing to non-native English speakers, since it can mean either "all" (e.g., "any positive number has a real square root") or "some" (e.g., "does this equation have any solutions?").  I think it is better to write "each" instead of "any" at the start of your question.

Comment: Have you seen the second paragraph of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6157.pdf?

Comment: For $n = 2$, this reduces to the question of when a matrix can be expressed as the product of two symmetric matrices, one nonsingular. More generally, if we have $A = BC$ with $B,C$ symmetric and $B$ nonsingular, then $A^t = CB$ is obviously similar to $A$. I wouldn't be surprised to see (though I don't have a full proof) that your problem can be reduced to that.

Comment: @KConrad's link as abs:  [Prasad, Singla, and Spallone - Similarity of matrices over local rings of length two](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6157).

Comment: I'd be interested to see your example over $\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @abx see Example 15 in http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf.

Comment: @KConrad I cannot find this PDF anymore. Is it available online?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No for $n\geq 3$.

If $A\in M_n(\mathbf Z_p)$ were similar to $A^T\in M_n(\mathbf Z_p)$, then going modulo $p^2$, its image in $M_n(\mathbf Z/p^2\mathbf Z)$ would be similar to the image of its transpose.

However, Pooja Singla, Steven Spallone and I have shown in [Similarity of matrices over local rings of length two](https://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/summaries.html#sim) that this fails for $n\geq 3$ (Theorem 7.9). For $n=3$ and $4$ we provide a classification and exact counts for matrices where this fails (see Table 9.4/ Table 8 in the arXiv version).

The answer is yes for $n=2$. This follows from Theorem 2.2 of [Similarity classes of 3x3 matrices over a local principal ideal ring](https://www.imsc.res.in/~amri/summaries.html#aopv)
. I thank @KConrad for nudging me to think this through.

Comment: Your $M_n(\mathbf Z/p^\mathbf Z)$ should probably be $M_n(\mathbf Z/p^2)$.  And what about $n = 2$?  (I'm glad to see your reply, since I had cited the arXiv version of it in a comment earlier.)

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo, and answered the 2x2 case.

Answer (score 15):

No, the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & p\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{M}_{3}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})
$$

is not similar to its transpose. This has been known for some time. McDonald, *Linear Algebra over Commutative Rings* (1984) atttributes this to M. Hochster in Exercise V.D.17, p. 424. More generally, it is noted there that this counter-example works for any commutative ring $R$ that is not von Neumann regular when instead of $p$ one uses an element $x\in R$ such that $x\not\in (x^2)$.

The "reason" why there is no counter-example for $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is that any such matrix can be written as $aI+p^iX$, where $a$ is a scalar and $X$ is a regular matrix, that is, $X$ is similar to a companion matrix. The point is that it is known that companion matrices over commutative rings are similar to their transpose (I think this is due to Gustafson).